# PowerShell how to open multiple instances of Excel

Tags: excel, powershell

My script is opened an Excel sheet from SPO and after the reading from the file and then I closing it.
The issue is when I run this script from 2 instances of PS (Ctrl + T)
While the first script is running all good but when the second script running I get a pop up message that the file is already opened
This is the script that read from the excel

```
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SharePointSiteURL
    $ExcelObject = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $ExcelWorkBook = $ExcelObject.Workbooks.Open($SharePointSiteURL)
    $ExcelWorkSheet = $ExcelWorkBook.Sheets.Item("VIP List")
    QuitExcel
 

function QuitExcel {
    # when done, quit Excel and remove the used COM objects from memory (important)
    $ExcelWorkBook.Close()
    $ExcelObject.Quit()
    $null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ExcelWorkSheet)
    $null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ExcelWorkBook)
    $null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ExcelObject)
    [System.GC]::Collect()
    [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
    Disconnect-PnPOnline
```

Answer (score 0):

While First script is accessing xls, definitely the second script which is accessing the same xls would cause an issue because it is in use. Alternate is to make a copy of the same xls on runtime and use it.